# UITableView Scrolling Slow When Using Non-English (Arabic, Chinese, Hebrew, Urdu, etc.) Text

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, scroll

I am using iOS 5 and making an iPad app. I have a UITableView in my app where every cell contains a UITextView. It experiences very slow scrolling, however, when non-English text is loaded into the text view.

This is a sample project I created to demonstrate the issue. This uses a UITableView where every UITableViewCell has one UITextView in it with a tag of 1. It scrolls very slowly:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BasicCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    textView.text = @"أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎. أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة‎.";
    return cell;
}
```

I have already used NSLog to verify that this line alone causes the slowdown. Removing it makes everything work perfectly, but I need to set the text. I've read everything I could find about performance tuning but this is still a huge problem for me.

Slow scrolling is only a problem with languages like Arabic, Chinese, Hebrew, etc. as opposed to English, French, German (maybe related to character sets or unicode?) An English string with 5000 characters has no slowdown at all but an Arabic string with 200 does.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Are the arabic long string static or are they dynamic (like pulled from a server)?

Comment: The strings are dynamic, but are fully loaded before the UITableView starts drawing. They are not changed at all during the rendering/drawing the cells.

Comment: Is it the requirement to fill the cell with the 500 char string? cant you just show some part of it?

Comment: Not in this case, because the user is able to make changes after it is loaded directly in any row's text view. That part is already optimized for performance, though to look into the current issue I have disabled this ability in my code until I resolve the slow scrolling issue. For our purposes it's loading the full text (note that it does not need to perform resize operations because the needed height is already cached).

Comment: Arabic must absolutely be _bombing_ the text renderer... I wonder if you could do this in core text instead.

Comment: @CodaFi - unfortunately, given the scope of the project, using core text would require creating a very unique interface that's extremely complicated because of some of the other features we have.

Comment: Then the only other alternative I can see is warning the user about the speed of the renderer.  Say that you're working on it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what is delaying the execution here is setting long text in an Editable UITextView

As per discussion, making UITextView to non-editable has increased the performance
I suggest to make it non editable and maybe later on changing it to editable

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Arabic for me. It works perfectly in English with any amount of text, but not in Arabic.

Comment: You are right i just tested it with UITextView and its indeed slow :S

Comment: The problem here is that you are using UITextView and when calling it from within the UI thread it slows, so i dont think that you can do it faster, you will have to implement a detailed view for editing the text

Comment: I've just stumbled on something: if I set textView.editable = NO before setting the text and then set it back to yes performance improves about 300% based on my NSLog tests. Maybe there is a way to use such hacks as a workaround?

Comment: Yes i think you could do something like that, start by textview.editable = NO, and then when the user taps on your cell, change it back to yes. 
Please if the answer helped you please consider to up vote, or/and accept it as an answer :)

Comment: What?  This will still run on the main queue (dispatch_get_main_queue()) and anyhow, if UIKit were even _remotely_ thread safe, this might work.

Comment: yes u r completely right i was considering editing the answer

Comment: He needs to get down and dirty in CoreText if this is ever going to render smoothly.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith - I did not mean to down-vote you, how do I undo this?

Comment: @CodaFi - What do you mean in your comment about dispatch_get_main_queue()? I don't understand.

Comment: When the code was up, he called a method named `+detachNewThreadSelector:` which would have created a background thread for your app to process on, but he defeated the purpose of it by calling `dispatch_get_main_queue()` which would have moved processing back to the main thread, thus ***slowing down*** text rendering.  Also, I downvoted him, not you.

Comment: Regarding the approach of setting UITextView to non-editable temporarily, there is still one issue that needs to be addressed for that to work: UITextView aligns all text left, even if it is RTL text like Arabic, when it is not editable. To make what we're discussing a valid workaround, we'll need to solve that problem first. I've search for solutions on that, but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: If you still have NSLog's in your code, remove them. They will be a large part of the slowdown.

Comment: Already did, I just needed them to find the line of code that was causing the slowdown. Great point though!

Comment: I created a separate question for the UITextView messing up RTL text when not editable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859471/non-editable-uitextview-left-aligns-rtl-arabic-hebrew-etc-text. If anyone can figure out that one, then the workaround we've been discussing for this question is viable.